# Preprocessor Definition in function parameter

Tags: c++, c

it is my first type to encounter this type of code. I am having a hard time understanding it.

```
#ifndef A
#define A
#endif

#ifndef B
#define B
#endif

void funct (structA* A paramA, structB* B paramB){};
```

What is the purpose of preprocessor A and B in the parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For:

```
#define A this_is_a
```

The preprocessor will replace `A` with `this_is_a`.

For:

```
#define A
```

The preprocessor will replace `A` with nothing.

So in your example code, `A` and `B` symbols are just discarded. People use this technique to annotate code sometimes, for example:

```
#define IN
#define OUT
```

Now you can annotate function parameters showing whether they are "in" or "out" parameters:

```
void my_function(IN int i, OUT int& x) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this (suppose your code is in `foo.h`):

## Non-const A

```
#include "foo.h"
...
```

## const A

```
#define A const
#include "foo.h"
```

Basically what your code does is that it allows adding a flag to the parameter. If no `A` macro is defined when the header is included, then it defines it as an empty string, so it is ignored. If the macro is defined, however, then its value is substituted into the signature.

Another usage is to select features based on compiler capabilities. For example:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CPP11
# define FORWARD_REF &&
# define FORWARD(T, x) std::forward<T>(x)
#else
# define FORWARD_REF const &
# define FORWARD(T, x) x
#endif

template <typename T>
void function_that_forwards_parameter(T FORWARD_REF t) {
    foo(FORWARD(T, t));
}
```